# Connect to MinIO in Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, minio

I have Minio in docker container called "be_minio". I want connect to that container with my app from another container called "be_api".

```
be_api:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - be_minio

be_minio:
    image: minio/minio
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9001:9001
    volumes:
      - ./volume_minio:/data
    command: server --address ":9000" --console-address ":9001" /data
    environment:
      ...
```

Config file with node sdk

```
const Minio = require('minio')

const minioClient = new Minio.Client({
    endPoint: "be_minio",
    port: 9000,
    useSSL: false,
    accessKey: ...,
    secretKey: ...
})

export default minioClient
```

But endPoint "be_minio" is not valid url.

```
S3Error: Invalid Request (invalid hostname)
```

Is there some solution for that ? E.g some networking, or something like that ?

Comment: Looks ok to me. 1. You could explicitly set hostname in docker-compos.yml for a service: `services: be_minio: hostname: sss`. 2. You could inspect your docker-compose project network (which is <folder_name>_default, unless stated otherwise): `docker network inspect <folder_name>_default` to check that your containers are in the same network. 3. You could `docker exec` into your "be_api" and try to ping "be_minio". 4. I would also try to use `-` instead of `_` in service names just in case.

Comment: Is the `be_minio` container failing somehow?  The file you show has no Compose network-related settings, which should normally be correct; does your actual file have any `networks:` or `network_mode:` settings?  To verify, the error message you're seeing is the output of `docker-compose up` or `logs`, and not from trying to run your code locally?

Comment: @DavidMaze There's no any network config. Containers runs on my vps.I tried run code, which interact with MinIO on my pc, set vps domain and port, it works, but not from container, tha's weird.

Comment: Are your containers run in single docker-compose? There should be a common network, if so.

Comment: @ILyaCyclone yes, in single docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

After long time of searching, trying, coding, etc, I found some mistakes, but what exactly caused the problem isn't clear.

1. Use dash in docker-compose service names instead of underscore
2. Envs are just strings
   `Boolean(process.env.ssl) ## Boolean("false") -> true`

Although I managed to get this working, when I generate public url, minioClient return docker-compose service name as domain :(.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems that the node client always uses the endpoint from the Minio.Client config for the presigned urls. A workaround is to add your docker service name to your local hosts file to redirect to 127.0.0.1. 
But I hope there is a better solution without that workaround.

Answer (score 1):

> Although I managed to get this working, when I generate public url, minioClient return docker-compose service name as domain :(.

You should be using X-Forwarded HTTP headers. Check this doc with Nginx as example: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/integrations/setup-nginx-proxy-with-minio.html

```
   location /minio {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rename host from `be_minio` to `be-minio`

https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/15006#issuecomment-1141639468

A member of the Minio team said that when naming hosts (minio hosts in docker), you should use a hyphen instead of an underscore. I had the same error `Invalid Request (invalid hostname)` and this advice helped me.

Comment: Please explain why you think doing this change will solve the problem. Maybe provide some code example of where they need to do the change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).